# Android Google Map project error: Couldn't get connection factory client

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.map"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

      <!--   <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" /> -->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library  android:name="com.google.android.maps" />  
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBmMPMq67L5SszRAOtIoC8Mag7M17TbKtc" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.jiachangyang.map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Layout

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.jiachangyang.map.MainActivity" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled = "true"
        android:apiKey="AIzaSyBmMPMq67L5SszRAOtIoC8Mag7M17TbKtc"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**These are xml file and layout file, I have no idea where is the problem. And also I did lots of research before, but seems there is no answers. I think many people have the same problem. Anyone can give me a solution, thank you.**

Comment: You are using GoogleMAp API Level1 which is already deprecated.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of errors?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using GoogleMap API v1 which is already deprecated.

Check [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey) :

**Note:** Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API as been officially
 deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012. This means that from March 3rd,
 2013 you will no longer be able to request an API key for this
 version. **This means that from March 3rd, 2013** you will **no longer be able to request an API key for this version.**

So, I would suggest you to migrate to [GoogleMap V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/):